Why is VBA Excel not returning the correct value in a cell with a formula?
I have the following code and for some reason, the value of all the cells with a formula in them changes to zero when the code executes a For loop.  The code where it happens is here:
Private Sub incomeAdd_btn_Click()
    Dim reslt As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim addrss As String
    Dim val As Variant
    
    clearingTransaction = True
    
    MsgBox ("1: The value of cell(6, 20) is " & Cells(6, 20).Value)
    
    'Warn
    reslt = MsgBox("This will add a new transaction to the ledger! Do you want to Continue?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2)
    If reslt = vbNo Then
        clearingTransaction = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    newTransaction = False
    IncomeAdd_btn.Enabled = False
    incomeModify_btn.Enabled = False
    incomeDelete_btn.Enabled = False
    
    'Blacken transaction bar cells
    Set myRange = Range("A6:F6, H6, J6:AG6")
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    
    'Get last row of logged income and assign nextRow value
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim maxRange As Range
    Dim nextRow As Long
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Set next empty row
    If lastRow = 18 Then
        Set maxRange = Range("A20")
        nextRow = 20
    Else
        Set maxRange = Range("A20:A" & lastRow)
        nextRow = lastRow + 1
    End If
    'Check certain non-required cells and assign default values if needed to cells...
    Set myRange = Range("A6,D6,E6")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        addrss = myCell.Address
        val = myCell.Value
        If (addrss = "$A$6") Then
            'Assign reference number
            Dim refNum As Integer
            If maxRange.Address = "$A$20" And IsEmpty(maxRange) Then
                refNum = 1
            Else
                refNum = getMaxValue(maxRange) + 1
            End If
            myCell.Value = refNum
        End If
        If (addrss = "$D$6") And IsEmpty(val) Then
            myCell.Value = "Miscellaneous"
        End If
        If (addrss = "$E$6") And IsEmpty(val) Then
            myCell.Value = "N/A"
        End If
    Next myCell
    
    MsgBox ("2: The value of cell(6, 20) is " & Cells(6, 20).Value)
    
    'Complete the transaction
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim myAmt_ciderStill As Currency
    Dim myAmt_ciderSpark As Currency
    Dim myAmt_wineStill As Currency
    Dim myAmt_wineSpark As Currency
    Dim myAmt_maltBev As Currency
    Dim myAmt_liquor As Currency
    Dim myAmt_food As Currency
    Dim myAmt_merch As Currency
    Dim myAmt_rental As Currency
    Dim myAmt_exempt As Currency
    Dim ciderSold_still As Double
    Dim ciderSold_spark As Double
    
    Dim ciderSold_red As Integer
    Dim ciderSold_black As Integer
    Dim ciderSold_blue As Integer
    
    Dim wineSold_still As Double
    Dim wineSold_spark As Double
    Dim maltBevSold As Double
    Dim liquorSold As Double
    
    Dim fedTax As Currency
    Dim paLiqTax As Currency
    Dim paWinExTax As Currency
    Dim paSaleTax As Currency
    
    Dim myCat As String
    Dim myQuarter As Integer
    Dim myRow As Integer
    
    MsgBox ("3: The value of cell(6, 20) is " & Cells(6, 20).Value)
    
    'Add the transaction to the transaction log
    For i = 1 To 33
    
        If i = 20 Or i > 29 Then
            MsgBox ("4: The value of Range(""T6"").Value is " & Range("T6").Value)
            MsgBox ("5: Cells(6, " & i & ").Value = " & Cells(6, i).Value)
        End If
        
        val = Cells(6, i).Value
        ...

MsgBox results 1 through 3 return the proper value of the cell as calculated by the cell formula and displayed on the worksheet, but results 4 and 5 result in a value of "0".  The other 4 cells that calculate values in the worksheet Cells(6, 30 - 33) display the correct values but also return "0" when tested at the same location in the code.  I have racked my brain over this for hours and can't seem to find a solution, even deleting the code and re-writing it several times.  I would appreciate any help!
I would expect that the correct value would be returned from Cells(6, i).Value, and can't understand why this is happening.  I am sure it was working earlier and then started returning zeros for the value of cells with a calculated value from a cell formula.

There's nothing happening (in your included code) between Msg 3 and Msg 4.  Seems like you haven't included some relevant lines.  And what is the formula in T20?  Seems like that's also relevant here.
